# Xcode4: Dependant projects and build configurations

Tags: iphone, xcode4, build-process

Assuming the following situation:
In Xcode I have a project which is dependent on the targets of projects B and C. When I now build my project A with the standard build configurations Debug or Release, these settings are propagated to the build process of the dependant targets.

If I create a custom build configuration "Debug_custom" the dependant target builds use Release. This is not only concerning the configurations but also the locations where the results are build to. B and C are build to "Release_iponeos" while A is build to "Debug_custom-iphoneos". The Linker fails.

What I want is to propagate the build settings as well as the build location. Is this possible without creating a similar config for every single dependant taget?

Unfortunately, I cannot use the workspace concept for this, due to other technical restrictions.

Comment: No. But a good option is to work with different targets instead of different configurations on a single target. This way some values can be inherited from the overall configuration and some can be explicitly set for the specific target.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into .xcconfig files?